# Mic not working properly

Tags: microphone, jack

I have a samsung notebook 3 with Ubuntu 20 running in it I actually use zoom but from past 2 days iam facing this problem where if I unmute myself and say something my voice is so meek that the receiver can't even get what iam saying I reinstalled zoom I restarted the machine but it's the same somebody please help even the earphones iam using I plug them and find the same issue with mic

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a levels problem.  You can check the levels in a few places.  Try the settings for your window manager.  If that doesn't help, try `pavucontrol` and if that still doesn't work, go to the terminal and try `alsamixer`